# Additional column with row numbering based on certain condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq that is working fine. However there is a space for fine tuning output list with row numbering. Rows are not duplicates as there different values in "Other columns...", however numbering should happen based on two columns ProjectNumber & SubProjectNumber.

Current list:

```
ProjectNumber SubProjectNumber Other columns...
    123              45
    123              45
    124              47
    125              48
    125              48
    126              49
```

I would like to add numbers this way using linq if possible:

```
 Pos   ProjectNumber SubProjectNumber Other columns...
  1        123              45
  1        123              45
  2        124              47
  3        125              48
  3        125              48
  4        126              49
```

I saw some examples available, but could not find any with field match aka where statement. I guess it should be somehow compared for `.GroupBy(g => new { g.ProjectNumber, g. SubProjectNumber}).Where(w => w.Key.Count() > 1)` (or am I completely wrong?)?

Here is my current linq:

```
                    var ListForHTMLTable = ListIntermediate
                            .Select(s => new
                            {
                                ProjectNumber = s.ProjectNumber,
                                SubProjectNumber = s.SubProjectNumber,
                                SubProjectLink = s.SubProjectLink,
                                ProjectType = s.ProjectType,
                                ProjectManager = s.ProjectManager,
                                ErrorType = s.ErrorType
                            })
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectNumber)
                            .ThenByDescending(x => x.SubProjectNumber)
                            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
 var ListForHTMLTable = ListIntermediate
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectNumber)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.SubProjectNumber)
    .GroupBy(s => new { s.ProjectNumber, s.SubProjectNumber })
    .Select((s, ix) => new { Pos = ix + 1, Data = s })
    .SelectMany(s => s.Data, (g, s) => new 
    {
        g.Pos,
        s.ProjectNumber,
        s.SubProjectNumber,
        s.SubProjectLink,
        s.ProjectType,
        s.ProjectManager,
        s.ErrorType,
    })
    .ToList();
```

You `.GroupBy` the data by `new { s.ProjectNumber, s.SubProjectNumber }`, then you add to each group the `Pos` column (there is an overload of `.Select` that gives you the index), then you "explode" the groups with `.SelectMany`.

Note that you can move the `.Select()` to the end of the expression, like I did.

Comment: is this can work as linq to SQL for sqlserver?

Comment: @KarimMoghnieh I don't know... This is surely good for "local" LINQ (`IEnumerable` objects, **not** `IQueryable` objects)... But you can try. The object in the question was named `ListIntermediate`, so a name for a materialized object.

Comment: Thanks a million, I have to investigate this in more detail.